# Make instruction apply to entirety of array?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

So I am currently fixing up a gun system that I have, and an issue that I have come across is the lack of ability to use any weapon but one.

I guess before I continue here is the code:

```
[Player Controller Script]
public Gun gun;


 void Update() {
    ControlMouse();

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Shoot"))
    {
        gun.Shoot(); 

    }
    else if (Input.GetButton("Shoot"))
    {
        if (gun.gunType == Gun.GunType.Explosive)
            {
                gun.ShootExplosive();
            }
        else if (gun.gunType == Gun.GunType.Auto)
        {
            gun.ShootContinuous();
        }

    }
```

Now this works fine but if I equip a second gun, it will not fire, as the "gun" is not changing away from the already set prefab. I tried adding on to the array of 'public Gun gun' by doing 'public Gun gun, gun1', and then adding 'gun1.Shoot()' to each if statement as with the original 'gun'. But that still did not work. I was wondering what I would need to do, to either have a) The 'public Gun gun' be dependent on whatever weapon with a certain tag is currently equipped or b) have that array work properly that I stated I tried before.

p.s: All guns are able to work fine independently (when their prefab is added to the player in the editor).

Comment: Am I right in assuming that the `Gun` class is one which you created with fields: `gunType` ennumerable to `Explosive` and `Auto`? and also you are deleting the current gun prefab and replacing it with a newly spawned one with all the propertiees that you want?

Comment: Yes are are correct to assume that. And yes I am, but one of the issues is that I can't find a way to do that with code when I pick up a weapon (it has to be done through the editor), as only the prefab that takes that slot will actually work.

Comment: Im not the most familiar with unity but could you represent the prefab in the gun class I.e. pass it by reference?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
[Player Controller Script]
public Gun gun;


 void Update() 
 {
    ControlMouse();

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Shoot"))
    {
        if (gun.gunType == Gun.GunType.Explosive)
        {
            gun.ShootExplosive();
        }
        else if (gun.gunType == Gun.GunType.Auto)
        {
            gun.ShootContinuous();
        } 
        else 
        { 
            gun.Shoot(); 
        }
    }
}
```

The first if is the only one that was ever executing which would mean that all guns would always shoot with the `Shoot()` method.

Comment: Interestingly enough, having the fixed version causes the problem you tried to solve xD For some reason, my incorrect version will work.

Comment: This version results in only a single shot as it will only execute on the button down

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to assign the gun variable to point to the new weapon:

```
gun = gun2.GetComponent<GunScript>();
```